# I keep on getting "signal SIGABRT" no matter how many times I recreate the App Delegate or the View Controller in new projects

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is the App Delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { (This is where signal SIGABRT is)
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

Here is the View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Cat: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel! 
    @IBAction func FindCatAge(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredAge = Cat.text.toInt()

    if enteredAge != nil {
        var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

        resultLabel.text = "Your cat's age is \(catYears) In cat years"
    } else {
        resultLabel.text = "Please enter a Number"
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I tried copy + pasting the code into a different project, a new one, made sure there were no other errors, did command + R to run the iOS simulator, then it brought be back to Xcode and at the bottom it said that the app was terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect your outlets to your views (i.e textField, button, etc)? If so make sure these connections are correct. You can inspect your connections by right clicking your views. It then shows all the connections the given view is doing.